# Passing a filter from a react table column to a cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Is it possible to pass a filter from an antd table column to the underlying cells in that column? for any other attribute attached to the column

something like this:

```
 {
    title: "Produktgruppe",
    dataIndex: "productGroup",
    width: "19%",
    filters: [
      { text: "001 - Bygning", value: "P001" },
      { text: "002 - Løsøre", value: "P002" },
      { text: "003 - Ansvar", value: "P003" },
      { text: "004 - Teknisk", value: "P004" },
      { text: "005 - Søvarer", value: "P005" },
      { text: "006 - Arbejdsskade", value: "P006" },
      { text: "007 - Diverse", value: "P007" },
      { text: "008 - Patientforsikring", value: "P008" },
      { text: "009 - Sundhedsforsikring", value: "P009" }
    ],
    filteredValue: filteredInfo.productGroup || null,
    onFilter: (value, product) => product.productGroup.code === value,
    sorter: (a, b) => this.compareString(a.productGroup.code, b.productGroup.code),
    sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === "productGroup" && sortedInfo.order,
    //render: productGroups => productGroups.displayName,
    render: (text, record, index, filters) => (
      <ProductGroupCell value={record.productGroup} availableProductGroups={filters} onChange={this.onCellChange(index, 'productGroup', products)} />
    ),
  },
```

thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
 availableProductGroups={filters}
```

is the line that I 'm wondering about.

Comment: made a list further up before defining my columns and passed it to both filters and availableProductGroups, however I can't seem to find a way to get the attributes of my cells column parent incase it had data or stuff I wanted to know about.

Comment: In the antd docs, I see that `render` for a `Column` component expects a callback of the form `function(text, record, index)`, so either your callback will be rejected for having the wrong number of arguments, or your `filters` param won't go through.

Comment: yeah I figured that out, I was just pseudo coding to show my interest of what I wanted.